# (Python) How to fix numerical representation error in dataframe column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, number-formatting

Just a (somewhat) quick question - if I have a dataframe with a column consisting of numbers of the form `1.305.000, 4.65, 99.9, 443.111.34000`, how can I convert them to the 'correct' format: `1305.000, 4.65, 99.9, 443111.34000`?

If it helps, the the values were obtained from a `.csv` file, from one of its columns, say 'Total Net Revenue':

In code block form:

```
Day Service Total Net Revenue
0   1   te  1.305.000
1   1   as  4.65
2   2   qw  99.9
3   3   al  443.111.34000
4   6   al  443.111.34000
5   6   te  1.305.000
6   7   pp  200
7   7   te  1.305.000
8   7   al  443.111.34000
9   7   te  1.305.000
```

And another form based on feedback:

```
[{'Day': 1, 'Service': 'te', 'Total Net Revenue': '1.305.000'},
 {'Day': 1, 'Service': 'as', 'Total Net Revenue': '4.65'},
 {'Day': 2, 'Service': 'qw', 'Total Net Revenue': '99.9'},
 {'Day': 3, 'Service': 'al', 'Total Net Revenue': '443.111.34000'},
 {'Day': 6, 'Service': 'al', 'Total Net Revenue': '443.111.34000'},
 {'Day': 6, 'Service': 'te', 'Total Net Revenue': '1.305.000'},
 {'Day': 7, 'Service': 'pp', 'Total Net Revenue': '200'},
 {'Day': 7, 'Service': 'te', 'Total Net Revenue': '1.305.000'},
 {'Day': 7, 'Service': 'al', 'Total Net Revenue': '443.111.34000'},
 {'Day': 7, 'Service': 'te', 'Total Net Revenue': '1.305.000'}]
```

I can't seem to find any reference on this, and some insight will be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Those are strings? `1.305.000` is no valid number. It might be a valid string representation if you change it to `1,305.000` (US) or `1.305,000` (Germany)

Comment: @PatrickArtner Hold on, I'll add in additional information which I accidentally left out.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I've added it! Sorry for the confusion, hope it helps.

Comment: Please share the csv - a few lines should be enough. As a guess: `1.305.000` would be 1.305 million - not 1305. `443.111.34000` is invalid however you turn it. Unless its some indian notation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system where they sometimes leave out some digits  ... cant find a reference right now

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks for the share and suggestions. I think the separators here will be `.`, and I've also added an image of how the csv looks like above

Comment: @Stoner it'd better instead of an image that you posted the top of the CSV file into a code block - that way, people can copy/paste it to create their own dataframe - even better would be if you could post the result of `your_df.head(10).to_dict(orient='records')` then people can directly use that in their REPL to re-create your DF.

Comment: @JonClementsThanks for your feedback. I've made the edits and I hope its better now.. I apologize for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't quite a pandas question, it's really asking about turning odd-looking strings into numbers (tag: number-formatting).

The following function will turn those strings into the desired numbers:

```
import unittest


def cleanup(s: str) -> float:
    parts = s.split('.')
    if len(parts) > 1:
        s = ''.join(parts[:-1]) + '.' + parts[-1]
    return float(s)


class TestCleanup(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_cleanup(self):
        self.assertEqual(200, cleanup('200'))
        self.assertEqual(4.65, cleanup('4.65'))
        self.assertEqual(1305, cleanup('1.305.000'))
        self.assertEqual(443111.34, cleanup('443.111.34000'))
```

You might consider using [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) if those are currency figures, which motivates a "scaled integer" approach.

It's a simple matter to [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) the `cleanup()` function to an existing dataframe:

```
df['numeric_revenue'] = df['total_net_revenue'].apply(cleanup)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and also the test cases! I'll be accepting your input as the answer as it works, though both answers technically work the same. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd define a function to parse the number and then use an `apply` on the dataframe's column. e.g.

```
def parse_number(number):
  split_number = number.split(".")
  return number if len(split_number) <= 1 else ".".join(["".join(split_number[:-1]), split_number[-1]])

df["parsed_value"] = df.value.apply(parse_number)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! However when I ran `df["parsed_value"] = df.value.apply(parse_number)` it did not work, and I had to perform `df["parsed_value"] = df["parsed_value"].apply(parse_number)` instead. Is there a specific reason why `.value` is used in such a manner?